# Cannot remove markers in Google Maps JS API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to remove all markers on map when the map is clicked.

I am following the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove

I've included the function:

```
function clearMarkers() {
  setMapOnAll(null);
}
```

to be triggered by a click event, but I just get the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: setMapOnAll is not defined

There is no other information in the documentation that can help me.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is indicating that setMapOnAll does not exist in the scope

```
// Sets the map on all markers in the array.
function setMapOnAll(map) {
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    markers[i].setMap(map);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes that how the example has it or you can just call them indivdually ie marker1.setMap(null)

Answer (score 2):

Responding to your last question, you do not really need to add the markers in an array, but be aware that in the documentation example, they add the word **var** before adding it in the array,

```
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map
    });
    markers.push(marker); ...
```

if you only want to work with just one marker then, do not add the **var** word

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({...
```

Then use `marker.setMap(null);` to get it out off the map.