# Google Maps API: Remove and reset markers on mouseover

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'de like to have all Markers set when initializing 
the page and when the mouse is out of the **div**. When the mouse is on one of the **div**, the Marker related to this **div** remains and the other ones are removed until mouseleave.

So I tried to remove all markers with **setMapOnAll(null)** and add the one specific to the **div** on mouseover, and then reset all markers on mouseleave.

But I cant make the Markers disappear.

Javascript:

```
  <script>
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    function initialize() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById("map"), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
          zoom: 13,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
      var name = "name1";
      var address = "address 1";
      var condition = "true";
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(42, -72);
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;

      var i = 0;
      createMarker(point, condition,html, i, map);

      point = new google.maps.LatLng(42.02, -72.02);
      name = "name2";
      address = "address 2";
      html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
      condition = "false";
      i++;
      var marker = createMarker(point, condition, html, i, map);

      map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
    }

    function createMarker(point, condition, html, i, map) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        draggable: true

      });
      var activeIcon, idleIcon;
      if (condition == "true") {
        idleIcon = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png';
      } else {
        idleIcon = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png';
      }
      marker.setIcon(idleIcon);

      var elem = document.getElementById('a' + i);
      if (!!elem) {
        elem.onmouseover = function() {
          setMapOnAll(marker, null);
          marker.setIcon(idleIcon);

        }
        elem.onmouseleave = function() {
          setMapOnAll(marker, map);

        }
      }
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);

      });

      return marker;
    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);

      });

    function setMapOnAll(marker, map) {
      for (var i = 0; i < marker.length; i++) {
        marker[i].setMap(map);
      }
    }
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

  </script>
```

html:

```
   <div id="a0">marker 1</div>
   <div id="a1">marker 2</div>
   <div id="map"></div>
```

CSS:

```
    html,
    body,
    #map {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px
    }
```

Comment: What is `setMapOnAll`? My fiddle works as is.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of _your_ code that demonstrates _your_ issue.

Comment: Thank your for your help. I was probably not clear enough in my explanations so I reformulated and edited my question: I'de like to have all markers set when initializing the page and when the mouse is out of the div. When the mouse is on a specific div, the Marker related to this div remains and all the others are removed until mouseleave. I cited your previous Fiddle because I thaught it would be a perfect basis to work on this new question.

Comment: Then I repeat: what is `setMapOnAll`?

Comment: Sorry, setMapOnAll(null) removes the markers from the map, but keeps them in the array and setMapOnAll(map) sets the map on all markers in the array. So I tried an approcach like : on div remove all markers and then add the one specific to the div and then on mouseover, reset all markers.

Comment: Please provide that code as part of the [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (it isn't complete if it doesn't include _all_ the code needed to run it)

Comment: Ok, I've re-edited the question.

Comment: I still don't see the function `setMapOnAll` defined in the posted code.  If you didn't include it, that would explain why it doesn't work (it isn't part of the API).  I get two javascript errors with your (newly) posted code: `Uncaught ReferenceError: setMapOnAll is not defined`, `Uncaught ReferenceError: markers is not defined` [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/5qk4zqz4/31/)

Comment: There is a version of  `setMapOnAll` in the question: [Cannot remove markers in Google Maps JS API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33621438/cannot-remove-markers-in-google-maps-js-api)

Comment: I tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/o6ruqv87/light/ with not much success.

Comment: 1. if you will have a large number of markers you want to be careful about how many times you iterate through the whole array.  2.  there still isn't any code for setMapOnAll **in your question**.  3. in your fiddle marker isn't an array (and as far as I can tell you don't create any array of markers)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. Unfortunately my javascript level is close to zero as except for the googlemap I never had to deal with this language. I don't think I can get much further now so I may come back in a moment if I understand a bit better!

Answer (score 0):

Just change the example in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34136082/google-maps-api-update-marker-color) to set the `map` property of the marker on mouseover of the external div, and set it back to null on mouseleave.

**code snippet:**

```js
function createMarker(point, icon, html, i, map) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: point,
    draggable: true

  });
  marker.setIcon(icon);

  var elem = document.getElementById('a' + i);
  if (!!elem) {
    elem.onmouseover = function() {
      marker.setMap(map);
    }
    elem.onmouseleave = function() {
      marker.setMap(null);
    }
    document.getElementById('a' + i).onclick = (function(marker) {
      return function() {
        google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
      }
    })(marker);
  }
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);

  });
  markers.push(marker);
  return marker;
}


var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var markers = [];
var map;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var name = "name1";
  var address = "address 1";
  var point = new google.maps.LatLng(42, -72);
  var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
  var i = 0;
  createMarker(point, 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png', html, i, map);

  point = new google.maps.LatLng(42.02, -72.02);
  name = "name2";
  address = "address 2";
  html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
  i++;
  var marker = createMarker(point, 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png', html, i, map);

  point = new google.maps.LatLng(42.01, -72.01);
  name = "name3";
  address = "address 3";
  html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
  i++;
  var marker = createMarker(point, 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png', html, i, map);
  map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="a0">marker 1</div>
<div id="a1">marker 2</div>
<div id="a2">marker 3</div>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```